# Dynamically change size of <div>s

Tags: html, css

I have a page set up so that my 2 `<div>` blocks (called, leftCol and rightCol) set to fill `25%` and `75%` of the page width, respectively. This is fine and good, but I need it to resize when the browser window grows or shrinks so that my text doesn't bleed into the column of pictures on the left.

Current CSS below

```
.leftCol {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.rightCol {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

I have tried using `width: auto` but that doesn't display the 2 columns as I wish at full screen width, giving me a line of images above the text instead of a column of pictures along the left side of the text as I wish. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nobody can really help you fix your problem without the rest of the code, you mentioned text but the code here just creates two responsive columns with no issues. Try adding a media query that places your columns on top of each other when the screen goes past a desired breakpoint, that gives you more room to fit text inside of your columns.

Answer (score 2):

Use `flex` on a container and wrap both `leftColumn` and `rightColumn` inside the container.

You can observe that text inside the columns will be wrapped to next line as you resize your browser window.

Assuming this is what you need as you did not post your source code.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.leftColumn {
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.rightColumn {
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftColumn">
    Left column content Left column content Left column content Left column content Left column content
  </div>

  <div class="rightColumn">
    Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content
    Right column content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should inquire about ***Media Queries***

With them you can create styles based on the resolution of the HTML

Source: [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a more modern way to set up your Layout with flexbox or CSS Grid Layout. And use some  media queries breakpoints for when the size of the window changes.
I cant see how is structured your whole site in html and css
but try and play with this.
Add a div in your html with a class named container that it wraps both left and right column and then on your CSS file:

```
.container {
   display:grid;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-areas: 
"columns columns columns";  
  }

.leftCol {
        display:grid;
        grid-area:columns;
        justify-content:start; 
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
      
    }
    
.rightCol {
        display:grid;
        grid-area:columns;
        justify-content:end; 
        width: 75%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use `width: 25%;`

Use `flex:1`**


if you use `width: 25%;` 
`padding` or `margin` will add `25%`
so total width will be increase, so container width will be greater than body width

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

 .container>.leftColumn{
  flex:1;
 }
 .container>.rightColumn{
  flex:4;
 }
 
 .container>*{
  background-color:#eeeeee;
  padding:10px;
  margin:5px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftColumn">
    Left column content Left column content Left column content Left column content Left column content
  </div>

  <div class="rightColumn">
    Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content Right column content
    Right column content
  </div>
</div>
```